# Can't See Product Options on Magento 1.4.2

Tags: magento

I did a fresh install of 1.4.2 to test it. All of my sites are currently on 1.4.0.1. When I add products I cannot see attributes as product options on front end. I've tested the system attributes and my super attribute extension. I've tried on simple and configurable products. It all seems to work on backend but they do not render on front end.

Answer (score 0):

Are you upgrading current products in your catalog from a previous version of magento or are these new products you creating in the admin?

Please clarify what you mean by attribute and product options... not sure what you mean since magento uses attributes(global) and custom options(per product).

My first attempt at helping you would be to uninstall any third-party extensions - it should lead you to the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kron. Was originally using an existing DB (from a 1.4.0.1 install) but then wiped DB and uploaded Magento sample DB. Built new products in backend on that DB but the whole install was acting fishy. Today I just wiped server clean and installed again, and wa la, no issues.(The demo DB with my new products worked just fine.)